# Multiple Occurrences of a Pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python and I'm trying to construct a list of tuples with the start and end indices for pattern matching in a string.

I need to match a pattern that starts with 2 consecutive 0s and ends with 2 consecutive 1s with some combo of 0s and 1s in between.

For example,

```
s = '00101010111111100001011'
```

With some type of operation returning,

```
[(0, 10), (15, 23)]
```

I can find multiple occurrences of a pattern in a string using,

```
ind = [(m.start(), m.end()) for m in re.finditer(pattern, s)]
```

I'm just not sure how to write the regular expression (i.e pattern) to output what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following pattern:

```
00[01]*?11
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0dD1YW/1)

**Details**:

- `00` - two consecutive `0`s
- `[01]*?` -  zero or more `0` or `1` chars, as *few* as possible (as `*?` is a lazy quantifier)
- `11` - two  consecutive  `1` chars.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/EaKzdn):

```
import re
s = '00101010111111100001011'
rx = r'00[01]*?11'
print([(x.start(),x.end()) for x in re.finditer(rx, s)])
# => [(0, 10), (15, 23)]
```